# How to add elements in list from a dropdown using Selenium/Python

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

[image]

I want to add all the city names in a list, so that I can compare then in assert is not in unit test.

Comment: Welcome. Next time, try to show us what you have done as well. People here should help you, not do the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

The above link gives the selenium documentation for python. I Believe that you are trying to get all the text in option tag and store it in a list

To get the text from multiple elements use below code:

```
a= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="fromPort"]/option').text;
print(a);
```

or ( If above code doesn't work)

```
elm= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="fromPort"]/option');
print([elm.text for elm in elems])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use will need to use getOptions() method of Select Class in Selenium. This will return a List of WebElements in the dropdown

Sample Code for your reference :

```
Select optionSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown_cities")));
List <WebElement> elementCount = optionSelect.getOptions();
```

Now you can iterate over this list and assert values as per your preferance.